# Layout, which will wrap it's content automatically?

Tags: java, layout, swt

I have a `composite A`, which should contains another `composite B`. 
`Composite B` will change it's size.

What layout should I apply to `composite A`, so that it will wrap `composite B` automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a `GridLayout` will work for you but keep in mind that you have to tell `compositeB` to `SWT.FILL` not the other way around:

```
Composite compositeA = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
compositeA.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

Composite compositeB = new Group(compositeA, SWT.NONE);
compositeB.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
```